# Propagating onclick functions with arguments by value

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm in a bind about how to propagate these `onclick` functions with useful arguments. I'm relatively new to js and I'm still getting used to the idea of functions as vars.

Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.level; i++) {
    var splotch = document.createElement('div');
    // ...
    // Omitted some styling and formatting
    // ...
    splotch.onclick = function() { switchColor(i); }; // The issue lies here
    pallet.appendChild(splotch);
}
```

The loop is designed to create a small pallet of colors which the user may choose from. The onclick events should be iteration-specific. That is, in HTML, the attributes would look something like:

```
onclick="switchColor(0)"
onclick="switchColor(1)"
// etc...
```

The argument however, is invariably the value of `i` that is one more than `this.level`, indicating to me that the *value* of `i` does not persist in each instance of the function, but rather the *reference* to `i`.

How might I mend this? And if my approach does not reflect best practice, I'd appreciate your adjustments.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: the `onclick` function, when clicked, will run in it's own scope and not within the scope of the for loop (which could have ended a long time ago as far as the page as concerned). `i` within the function ends up acting like an implicit global, which, since you (likely) ran the for loop in global scope means that `i` is persisting from the last iteration of the loop. As in the possible duplicate, a solution can be something like: `function createSwitchColor(x) {
        return function () { switchColor(x) };
    }

    //... code
    splotch.onclick = createSwitchColor(i);`